# Expand / collapse code devices invisible in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Since starting up Visual Studio 2008 this morning, the little devices at the left-hand side of the edit screens to allow one to expand or collapse the source code have been invisible. They still work; if you guess where to click, the code expands or collapses as one might expect.

I've checked all the colour dialogues and I don't *think* I've set anything to have the background and foreground colours the same.

Does anyone know what the problem might be, or what the official name for these things is so that I can find the right setting in the dialogues or help text?

Comment: If you back up your settings, then reset them, does the issue go away?

Comment: @soandos, yes, thanks, but the settings I got back weren't the ones I saved so I think I got it wrong somewhere.

Comment: Should I write this as the answer?

Comment: @soandos, if you do, I'll tick it; thanks for your suggestion.